# Spring boot + Embedded Kafka + h2 database + unit Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka, h2

So I am using this example [Embedded Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753051/simple-embedded-kafka-test-example-with-spring-boot) and [this too](https://github.com/YunaBraska/embedded-kafka-example)

I have changed this example little bit and updated the kafka listener with some database (Like h2 db).

Now in my unit test when I want to check that data is available in DB or not I am getting NULL. Also I am not sure how to check DB manually as h2 is a memory base DB.

here is the updated part:
in receiver class

```
@Autowired
DataTableRepository repository;

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafkatest.topic}")
public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, DataTable> consumerRecord) {
    LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.toString());
    repository.save(consumerRecord.value());
    latch.countDown();
}
```

And in unit test :

```
@Autowired 
DataTableRepository repository;

@Test
public void testReceive() throws Exception {
DataTable table = new DataTable(1, "Sending with default template");

template.send(topic, table);

receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

DataTable dt = repository.getOne(table.getId());
assertNotNull(dt);
assertThat(receiver.getLatch().getCount(), equalTo(0L));
}
```

But dt is always getting null. Also i am not able to check Database also, as it get stopped after test stopped.
Anybody has any idea how to make this workable?

Comment: When running your test do you see the log "received payload=..." ?

Comment: @NAIT No, i can't see any log from service

Comment: This means that kafka listen method haven't been called

Comment: Possible, but how to call it through unit test?, ideally it should pick the data from kafka topic as it is integrated with EmbeddedKafka which provide all the feature for kafka. Or I am following a very wrong example for this integration?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the property "kafkatest.topic" in the test properties file? That might be the reason that your listener is not listening to the topic specified.