# spring embedded kafka with junit5 - No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap servers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I'm trying to use Embedded kafka for my tests.I'm using spring boot and junit5 as follows

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka
public class MyTest {
//Instead of the class rule approach I'm using
EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1,true,topics);
..
@Test
public void myTestCase() {
....

}
```

However,my tests fail with the `No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap servers`

I'm using a test profile too where on the yml file I've

```
 bootstrap-servers :{spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`@SpringBootTest` initializes the test Spring Boot application context before the test class instance is created and member fields are initialized. Because of that the `@SpringBootApplication` doesn't see the `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` as the field is initialized later.

Try following [a working example from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756251/1602555):

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableKafka
@EmbeddedKafka(
    partitions = 1, 
    controlledShutdown = false,
    brokerProperties = {
        "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:3333", 
        "port=3333"
})
public class KafkaConsumerTest {
    @Autowired
    KafkaEmbedded kafkaEmbeded;
}
```

Comment: Right - the OP has two brokers, the one added to the Spring context via the annotation and the field initialized manually; autowiring the `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` is the correct approach (`KafkaEmbedded` is deprecated in 2.2.x and doesn't exist in current versions). Just for completion, `@EmbeddedKafka` works with a vanilla (non-spring) test as well, via the `EmbeddedKafkaCondition`, and the broker instance is available via `EmbeddedKafkaCondition.getBroker()` to get access to the broker URL(s).

Comment: With Spring Boot tests, you can also use `@EmbeddedKafka(..., bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")` to override the boot property in application.yml.